# 2 text fields mapped to same formcontrolname angular 2+

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have a requirement where in i have 2 search fields one on top and one on bottom. Need to keep both text fields in sync i.e. user can type in top or bottom search text box. If he types in top box it should reflect in bottom box and vice versa. I am using reactive angular forms

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:-

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="searchBox1">Search Box 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchBox1" name="searchBox1" 
                    formControlName="searchBox" placeholder="Search Box 1" (change)="addText($event.target.value)">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="searchBox2">Search Box 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchBox2" name="searchBox2" 
                formControlName="searchBox" placeholder="Search Box 2" (change)="addText($event.target.value)">
      </div>
</form>
```

**component.ts** code:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'searchBox': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  addText(value) {
    this.form.setValue({
      'searchBox': value
    });
  }
}
```